# Will a separate JSON-LD snippet help in enhancing latest NewsArticle on homepage?

Tags: rich-snippets, json-ld, homepage

Although I mark-up all my `NewsArticle` items using JSON-LD, but I want to know that if for the homepage till the time the latest articles remain on the homepage (usually 24hrs), will it be good (Google giving more privilege) if I add JSON-LD snippets to the homepage code for all articles which are there for the time being?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would follow Googles guidelines for lists of things and carousels:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings

In your case the home page is a summary page, so they recommend just marking up a list of items with the url for each article.

Comment: Thanks, will update if I find something better. Till then will experiment with this one.

Answer (score 0):

JSON/LD is a format of structured data that helps the search engines to understand content but still without structured data the search engines can understand your content but adding structured data makes the search engines ready to understand.
and this will also help you to increase the probability of getting more place in search.

It's always the same either for home page article or any other article.